# NSDateIntervalFormatter printing dates even when dateStyle is set to NSDateFormatterNoStyle

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, foundation

I'm using `NSDateIntervalFormatter` to format a range of hours. They're always on the same day, so I don't want to show the date. In a US English locale, they would look something like 9:00 PM - 10:00 PM.

The problem arises when the time crosses over midnight. Then, the end date is technically on the next day, and `NSDateIntervalFormatter` prints the date, even though its `dateStyle` is set to `NSDateFormatterNoStyle`:

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
comps.year = 2015;
comps.month = 5;
comps.day = 12;
comps.hour = 21;

NSDate *startDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comps];

// next day, at midnight
comps.day = comps.day + 1;
comps.hour = 0;
NSDate *endDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comps];

NSDateIntervalFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateIntervalFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];

formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;
formatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;

NSString *string = [formatter stringFromDate:startDate toDate:endDate];
NSLog(@"%@", string);
// expected: 9:00 PM - 12:00 AM
// actual: 5/12/2015, 9:00 PM - 5/13/2015, 12:00 AM
```

Is there any way to get it to always hide the date, without having to just format two dates separately and join them with a dash?

Comment: After further investigation (thanks, Brian!), this appears to be an Apple bug. I [filed a radar](http://www.openradar.me/20938435). Going to fall back to concatenating the results of two `NSDateFormatter`s with a localized format string.

Answer (score 2):

If you eliminate the Y/M/D from the date components it works as desired:

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
//    comps.year = 2015;
//    comps.month = 5;
//    comps.day = 12;
comps.hour = 21;

NSDate *startDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comps];

// next day, at midnight
comps.day = comps.day + 1;
comps.hour = 24;
NSDate *endDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comps];

NSDateIntervalFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateIntervalFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];

formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;
formatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;

NSString *string = [formatter stringFromDate:startDate toDate:endDate];
// string = 9:00 PM - 12:00 AM
```

Also interesting is if comps.day + 1 is removed, it shows:

```
1/3/1, 9:00 PM - 1/4/1, 12:00 AM
```

Which to me makes no sense.... 1/3?!

*Update:* It appears to be have the correct result only when endDate is one day before startDate. It does not if it's more than a day off. This feels like undefined territory, not working as desired.